# c++ dynamical array in class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, function

I'm programming a hotel program that contains array

//size of array is number of rooms in that hotel

//array[i] contains people in room i, max is 3 people

everything works perfectly (constructor,copy constructor,destructor) I check it by print function (it prints array's content -zeros)

until I relaised that status function (defined in class) filled array content automatically with some number!

```
void status (const Hotel& o){

    for (int i=0 ;i<o.numofrooms ;i++ ) {

if (o.arrayptr[i]=0)

    cout<<"Room number "<<i<< " is available"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"Room number "<<i<< " is unavailable"<<endl;

 }


}
```

prints all rooms are unavailable! Who are there :D

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between = and ==

Comment: I explained it above, it's logically error

Comment: I have fallen for this before, I know how it feels.

Comment: @JamesEldridge haha I hope we won't do it again

Comment: @Beginner Don't hope; turning up the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
if (o.arrayptr[i] == 0); // you're using the assignment '=' instead of the comparison '=='
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making all array items 0 by executing

```
o.arrayptr[i]=0
```

instead of

```
o.arrayptr[i]==0
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, change if (o.arrayptr[i]=0) to if (o.arrayptr[i] **==** 0).

In order to capture such mistakes, always put the constant on the left hand side of an equality comparison. For example:

```
if (0 = o.arrayptr[i]) // flagged as an error by the compiler.
```

One reason is that if you leave out one of the = signs, the compiler will find the error for you.

Comment: Welcome, well that's a standard practice often used as part of the good coding conventions in industries.